# PermissionsStartOnly alternative in systemd

Tags: linux, systemd

I found `PermissionsStartOnly` setting in `systemd` is already deprecated [according to systemd's NEWS file](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/60b45a80c1f98bad000bd902d97ecf6c4e3fc315/NEWS#L2434).

> PermissionsStartOnly= setting is deprecated (but is still supported
> for backwards compatibility). The same functionality is provided by
> the more flexible "+", "!", and "!!" prefixes to ExecStart= and other
> commands.

I should use `+` or `!` or `!!`, but I am not sure how to use this option even I have read the manual.

My `myservice.service` is as follows. How can I rewrite this without `PermissionsStartOnly`?

```
[Service]
PermissionsStartOnly=true
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c '/bin/journalctl -b -u ntpdate | /bin/grep -q -e "adjust time server" -e "step time server"'
ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /path/to/somedir
ExecStart=/path/to/myservice
ExecStop=/bin/kill -INT ${MAINPID}
ExecReload=/bin/kill -INT ${MAINPID} && /path/to/myservice
Restart=always
RestartSec=5
User=myuser
Group=mygroup
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Setting **PermissionsStartOnly=true** means that User & Group are only applied to **ExecStart**.
So switching to the new syntax will be :

```
ExecStartPre=+/bin/bash -c '/bin/journalctl -b -u ntpdate | /bin/grep -q -e "adjust time server" -e "step time server"'
ExecStartPre=+/bin/mkdir -p /path/to/somedir
ExecStart=/path/to/myservice
ExecStop=+/bin/kill -INT ${MAINPID}
ExecReload=+/bin/kill -INT ${MAINPID} && /path/to/myservice
```

1 -  **ExecStart** will be executed with less privilege, which also means executed as "User" & "Group"

2 - The statements prefixed with "+" will be executed with higher privilege as **root**.
So in this case you will have only **ExecStart** that will be executed with "myuser" & "mygroup"